# Alternatives to using CSV in JMeter (for generating usernames)

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a JMeter Test Plan with following structure

```
Test Plan

**ThreadGroup1**
--CSV Data Config-001
----SimpleController
--------------LoginRequest
--------------Action-abc-Request

**ThreadGroup2**
--CSV Data Config-002
----SimpleController
--------------LoginRequest
--------------Action-xyz-Request
```

I have two CSV files which contain list of users like this..

```
**CSV-001**
Username1
Username2
.. ..
Username50

**CSV-002**
Username51
Username52
.. ..
Username100
```

In my scenario, I need to run a load test with say 100 users. 50 users login from ThreadGroup1 and other 50 users login from ThreadGroup2. Users from both threadgroups login simultaneously.

Currently, I have to go through process of manually creating/editing these CSV files whenever I change the number of total users.

Please suggest if there are any **alternative time-saving & performance-efficient** approaches through I which can fulfill my scenario requirements (without using CSV files).

I will appreciate, if you can explain the alternative solution with some details as I am quite new to JMeter stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Moreover, can someone please comment on possible performance benefits of using CSV over any other approaches? Why do I see that most people use it only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another idea is to use

`Username${__threadNum}`

for the first thread group and

`Username${__BeanShell(ctx.getThreadNum()+Z+1)}`

for the second, where Z equals the total number of threads in thread group 1.  You also need to add 1 since ctx.getThreadNum() returns a thread number using a 0 based index, whereas the __threadNum function is 1 based.

Comment: I used your previous solution (along with Synchronizing timer) and it worked for great me. I liked your this solution even more as It simplifies things further. But I am having a minor issue with this solution. ".getThreadNum() in second function returns "0" value for first thread and because of that I get username which is actually performing actions from ThreadGroup1. Can you please suggest a workaround that??

Comment: For example if I configure 3 users for ThreadGroup1 and 3 users for ThreadGroup2. Then the result is like this... username1, username2 & username3 for ThreadGroup1. Where as username3, username4 & username5 for ThreadGroup2. [USERNAME3 being logged in twice].

Comment: I updated the answer above such that is should work with ThreadGroup2 now.

Comment: That was quite simple. Solution works perfectly now. Accepted as answer. Thanks a lot for all your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter in each thread.  The start value for the counter in the first thread would be 1, in the second 51.  Be sure the 'Track counter independently for each user' check box is unchecked.

If you set the reference names to thread1Count and thread2Count respectively, you can use

```
Username${thread1Count}
```

for the first thread and

Username${thread2Count}

for the second.

Comment: JusMe, Thanks for the answer. I have tried this solution and even though it works but I observe there are some changes in pattern of requests execution with this approach (as compared to using CSV).

When I run the JMeter script using CSV, then all the login requests are executed almost simultaneously with very little time gap. Whereas with counters, the pattern of request execution is kind of in Loop. For example if there are total 5 requests in a thread group, then sequence of requests execution is like this .. 1) user1 - 5 requests 2) user2 - 5 requests and so on..